# Dot Emacs: Can frame-title-format show preceding directories?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm new to Emacs and loving it so far.
In my .emacs I have the line:

`(setq frame-title-format "%b - GNU Emacs")`

How can I get it to show the two preceding directories? I tend to have multiple files open with the same name and knowing the directory it is in would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `uniquify` is a more complete solution to your problem. See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Uniquify.html